# Call AngularJs Service from ng-Change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below AngularJs Service that load data. I also have a dropdown on the page, I need to reload the getallData() service through ng-change on the dropdown. How do I call it?

**Service**

```
app.service("VacancyService", ['$http', '$location', function ($http, $location) {

    this.getAllData = function () {
        var response = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/GetAllData'
        });
        return response;
    }

}]);
```

**Html**

```
 <select ng-model="selectedVacancy" ng-options="x.name for x in vacancieslist" ng-change=""></select>
```

Comment: Whatever provides `selectedVacancy` needs to inject the service and also provide a function that delegates to it.

Comment: @Sheraz Khan ,Add the service dependency to it and Create a method in the controller. call the service method via the controller. :-)

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, any possible example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1) In `ng-change`, call a controller function:

```
<select ng-model="selectedVacancy" 
         ng-options="x.name for x in vacancieslist" 
         ng-change="getVacancyData()">
</select>
```

#### 2) In your controller, define the `getVacancyData()` function (that call the service):

```
$scope.getVacancyData = function() {
    VacancyService.getAllData().then(function(response) {
        $scope.vacancieslist = response.data;
    });
}
```

---

Note: Be sure the VacancyService is [**injected**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in your controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'VacancyService', function($scope, VacancyService) {
    ...
}]);
```

Comment: good one. But I don't know why he calling the service on ng-change. because he didn't use `checkObjectType` to the service

Comment: @Ramesh Agreed, that's strange. But from the question I can not guess what he really intends to do...

Comment: I have create function and calling that function from ng-change. It does fire the method but its not updating the rendered list. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller for same and call the service in the controller

```
app.controller('VacancyCtrl', function($scope, VacancyService) {
    $scope.vacancyData = function(){
        VacancyService.postLargeTicket().then(function(response){
         //do you thing here
        }, function(){
        });
   };
```

Call your method here in html

```
<select ng-model="selectedVacancy" 
         ng-options="x.name for x in vacancieslist" 
         ng-change="vacancyData()">
</select>
```